# error de actualizar en fullcalendar

Tags: php

Estoy realizando un proyecto de citas en `fullCalendar`, pero el apartado de actualizar `(UPDATE)`, no realiza ninguna acción.

```
case 'modificar':
             //Instruccion de modificar
    $sentenciaSQL=$pdo->prepare("UPDATE eventos SET
    title=:title,
    descripcion=:descripcion,
    color=:color,
    textColor=:textColor,
    start=:start,
    end=:end,
    WHERE ID=:ID
    ");

    $respuesta= $sentenciaSQL->execute(array(
        "ID" =>$_POST['id'],
        "title" =>$_POST['title'],
        "descripcion" => $_POST['descripcion'],
        "color" => $_POST['color'],
        "textColor" =>$_POST['textColor'],
        "start" => $_POST['start'],
        "end" => $_POST['end'],
    ));
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
                break;
        default:
            //Seleccionar los Eventos del Calendario
            $sentenciaSQL=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM eventos");
            $sentenciaSQL->execute();

            $resultado= $sentenciaSQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            echo json_encode($resultado);
        break;
```